# How to write a complex SQL query in query DSL

Tags: java, querydsl

I try to calculate percentage of amout of a specific product per total amout of products. I wrote a SQL query that works fine.
But when i try to write in Query DSL I encountred a problem , i really have a problem to write this kind of query.

```
SELECT ROUND((c.v2/f.v1)*100,2) , MONTH AS RESULTt
FROM
(SELECT SUM(Quantite)as v1,MONTH  FROM Total_sold_view WHERE id_company='379' AND
year=2009 GROUP BY MONTH ORDER BY MONTH ASC) f,
(SELECT Quantite as v2,MONTH FROM Total_sold_view  WHERE id_company='379' AND year=2009
AND product_type=13 ORDER BY MONTH ASC) c
WHERE c.MONTH=f.MONTH
```

Comment: Try to simplify the query at first, I don't believe you can put the second subquery as a top level query and then you can reduce the first subquery to return the sum only.